# Partial escaping of characters between MVC and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, escaping

**Background**

Keeping the double backslash between server side and client side.

**View Model**

```
MyViewModel.Users { get "'domain\\user1', 'domain\\user2'"; }
```

**Markup**

On the page I output using:

```
var userArray = [ @Html.Raw(Model.Users) ];
```

**Problem**

viewing source shows:

```
var userArray = [ 'domain\user1', 'domain\user2' ];
```

This is causing errors. I want to keep the single quotes but double escape the backslash.

TIA....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double escaping a backslash would be `"\\\\"` in C#.

This gives you an internal string that has two backslashes.

Comment: How did i miss that !? I only need a quick solution. This works a treat.